# Is it possible to automatically sync or schedule backup from windows desktop to Amazon cloud drive?

Tags: cloud-storage

Amazon recently announced unlimited photo storage on their cloud drive for Prime members. I'd like to use that feature, but I don't want to manually upload photos every time I have new ones.
Usually I take pictures with my camera, then drop them into a folder on Window box. Is it possible to automatically sync content of that folder to Amazon cloud drive or schedule backup of that folder to Amazon cloud drive?

Comment: http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-s3-powershell.aspx and http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/how-to-sync-local-folder-with-amazon-s3-bucket-with-cloudberry-s3-explorer/

Comment: Have you tried the Amazon Cloud Drive desktop application?

Comment: @STTR S3 != Amazon Cloud Drive.  AFAIK, Cloudberry doesn't support Amazon Cloud Drive.

Comment: @heavyd desktop app seem to only support manual "drag to upload" or "browse folder to upload" very basic. Guess I will have to look into 3rd party apps that support cloud drive

Comment: Looking for this on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately this [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/2lhwfu/amazon_cloud_drive_sync_now_retired_where_can_i/) pointed to archive copy of old version of [Amazon Desktop App](https://web.archive.org/web/20140415073542/https://www.amazon.com/gp/drive/app-download?ie=UTF8&ref_=cd_kindle_desk_dwld) that supports syncing. Works like magic. Why Amazon removed sync feature in the new version is beyond me.

Answer (score 3):

odrive supports syncing to/from various cloud storage services, including Amazon Cloud Drive.  I've found it to be a decent piece of software, though the CPU usage is a bit high at times on my Windows 8 machine.  Good functionality, though.  Access to multiple cloud storage solutions in a Dropbox-like way with a single client program.

EDIT: I've found a solution to the high CPU usage on Windows; if I disable "expand to current location" by right-clicking in the folder pane of File Explorer, then it no longer noticeably bogs the CPU down.

In addition to the Windows (7+) and Mac GUI versions, they also now have a "headless" version which runs on Linux, Windows, or Mac (using Python, so perhaps anywhere Python will run as well?)

So, now I can more wholeheartedly endorse it as something that can provide a Dropbox-like file syncing experience with Amazon Cloud drive.

I also found Cloudberry's offerings to be useful for manually copying back and forth from my older Win XP machine, which odrive will not support.

Answer (score 3):

[GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/) is an awesome program for that. I've been using it for years and currently use it to backup to my unlimited Amazon Cloud Drive. It's not free but reasonably priced.

> GoodSync synchronizes and backs up files such as photos, financial
>   documents, MP3s, and e-mails between desktops, laptops, servers, and
>   external drives.
>
> GoodSync is the latest software in a series of highly reliable,
>   easy-to-use products from Siber Systems, the makers of RoboForm. It
>   uses an innovative synchronization algorithm that offers true
>   bi-directional synchronization.

http://www.goodsync.com/how-to-sync-amazon-cloud-drive

Comment: Although I love Goodsync for such a case ,but the new subscription policy of it (which I don't like) lead me suggest another two perfect options that have similar options to upload directly to AWS like Duplicati and Gs Richcopy360 , both have options to run automatically , schedule tasks and limit the upload speed

Answer (score 2):

Saw [Heavyd's](https://superuser.com/questions/836764/is-it-possible-to-automatically-sync-or-schedule-backup-from-windows-desktop-to#comment1100992_836764) comment, don't know how supporting Amazon Cloud Drive was in 2014 when you posted, but I checked it and CloudBerry for sure do now. To be exact, here's a direct link to [CloudBerry for Amazon Cloud Drive.](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-cloud-drive-tools.aspx)
Never used it yet, but was pleased to see the price. I bet it will help you to automate the backup.

And [Yuriy Galanter](https://superuser.com/users/225109/yuriy-galanter) your second link is broken unfortunately, I was curious to see some 'magic'.

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Drive app gallery is a good place to look: https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/apps.

ODRIVE: odrive seems to be the straightforward choice since it is one of the top Featured Apps and specifically mentions desktop sync in its description.  There's a video which shows how sync works (similar to Dropbox/Google Drive), but there's a twist about how it has placeholder files to save disk space.  It's a short 2-min video clip: https://www.odrive.com/amazon-drive-sync.  I've used odrive for a while and I like it a lot because I have a lot of cloud storage accounts (in addition to Amazon Drive), so it helps me stay organized.

EXPANDRIVE: they seem to offer a "network drive" style interface. So it's more like direct saves to the source. This is probably good if you're always connected to the internet and are working with smaller files. But it's a little different than sync.

CLOUDHQ: this looks like it replicates stuff between clouds, which is different than syncing files between your computer and Amazon Drive. It looks interesting if you are worried about backing up stuff that is already in the Amazon Drive / don't trust Amazon Drive to be completely reliable or available.

CLOUDBERRY: They have an "Explorer" product which looks like an S3 Browser or Cyberduck-like interface to different storage.  Not sync, but could be effective for just getting files up. They also have a "Backup" product as well which supports Amazon Drive.

ARQ: Backup solution.  I've seen this come up in several forums (usually it's odrive and arq that are mentioned), but I haven't used this before.

CLOUDSYNC and QNAP: Specific solutions if you own a NAS from Synology or QNAP. I own a Drobo, so I couldn't use these, but I would have liked to have tried them out if I could.

---

Separately, as seen from google web searching...

GOODSYNC: Goodsync seems to show up in search results, but when I look at their website product pictures, it doesn't give me a whole lot of confidence. It seems more like manual sync than automatic, in-line sync (Dropbox-style, like odrive provides) through Finder/Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Found even better solution. Currently using Synology DiskStation for local backups and it has many pretty cool installable packages. One of then is "Cloud Sync" that syncs to many different cloud services - including Amazon Cloud Drive.